# Asci.SqlDmo.Interop, Version=14.0.0.0' not found when running SQL Server Agent job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I am attempting to run a SQL Server agent job from an outside scheduler on SQL Server 2017 (v14) and when doing so I am encountering the following error(s):

> SMO failed with the following exception:
>
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> FileNotFoundException in step 'SQLServerJob': Could not load file or assembly 'Asci.SqlDmo.Interop, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ec7e0636adb4f415' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have another server that should be setup in the same manner that is not throwing the same error.

However I've checked the registry for both servers and was unable to find SMO or SqlDmo on either. Any help would be appreciated.